# Is 512 MB RAM Really Enough for Android ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, performance

(Background: I never use ICS Phone, so i want to ask about performance)

Some of Android ICS Phone (e.g. Xperia J, Xperia Sola) has 512 MB RAM. How about performance of Android ICS Phone with that amount of RAM? [Sony Developer Blog](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/03/30/learn-about-the-technical-differences-between-gingerbread-and-ics/) said that there is performance issue with only 512 MB RAM, but is it really matter to user?

Comment: It should work, I'd say. See my profile: I run a HTC Wildfire with 4.0.4 (CM9). The Wildfire/Buzz has 384 MB RAM. As said: Here it *works*, but with 2.3.6 (CM7) it was a little smoother. Hard at the limit :)

Comment: Just a note: Stack Exchange works best on questions about _actual problems you are facing_.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something the slimROMs team  provides. Check this out: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2114002

Answer (score 0):

I have an LG Optimus 2X. Same, 512 MB of Ram. I've used ICS. Now I'm on Jellybean(4.1- CM10).
 I've never had a problem using the phone. (Heck it because so much smoother in JB). The only problem is that certain memory hungry apps like Chrome are a tad bit laggy.

Answer (score 0):

I think smoothness depends more on the processor/gpu/chipset than RAM. RAM is of course still important but 512MB should be enough. More RAM is only needed for multitasking, so android does not immediately kill background apps when memory is low.